# PHP: How to create stdClass array with sorting another 02 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays as bellow,

1. contains work hours for a given Task of a Project Structure. and information like below,
   [projectname] - name of the project

   [structurename] - name of structure (project has many structures)

   [taskname] - name of the Task (structures have many tasks)

   [taskstartdate] - starting date of the task

   [estimatedhours] - Estimated hours for the task

   [hours] - number of hours an employee worked on the task

   [createdon] - the date that employee worked number of hours

   ```
   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => test p1 [structurename] => test structure [taskname] => task [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-02 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 10.00 [hours] => 5.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-03 07:38:08 )
           [1] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => test p1 [structurename] => test structure [taskname] => task [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-02 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 10.00 [hours] => 2.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-04 14:21:34 )
           [2] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => p2 [structurename] => struc [taskname] => p2t1 [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-03 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 8.00 [hours] => 2.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-04 11:05:31 )
           [3] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => p2 [structurename] => struc [taskname] => p2t1 [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-03 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 8.00 [hours] => 6.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-05 08:00:22 )
           [4] => stdClass Object ( [projectname] => web dev [structurename] => dev test [taskname] => dev task [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-04 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 30.00 [hours] => 8.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-04 08:21:14 ))
   ```
2. The second array contains days for a given week (in this case, first week of the 2016, February)

   ```
   Array ( [0] => 2016-02-01
           [1] => 2016-02-02
           [2] => 2016-02-03
           [3] => 2016-02-04
           [4] => 2016-02-05 )
   ```

**Using the both above arrays I want to create one single array object as below**,
The idea behind this is to create one row of array for one project and add worked hours for given 05 days. The description of the expected array as below,

[name] - Combination of [projectname] | [structurename] | [taskname] of the very first array

[taskstartdate] - Task start date from the first array

[estimatedhours] - Estimated hours from the first array

[01] - Get 01 from 2016-02-01 and add as key, from the second array

[02] - Get 02 from 2016-02-02 and add as key, from the second array

[03] => 5.00 -  Get 03 from 2016-02-03 and add as key, from the second array
                and also add 5.00 as value.

This is because of the first array [hours] = > 5.00 [createdon] => 2016-02-03 07:38:08 which means an employee has worked 5 hours on 2016-02-03 so it should be added as the value.

[04] => 2.00 - according to the [1] => stdClass Object of the first array employee has worked on the same project 2.00 hour on 2016-02-04

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => test p1 | test structure | task [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-02 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 10.00    [01] => 0 [02] => 0 [03] => 5.00 [04] => 2.00 [05] => 0)
         [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => p2 | struc | p2t1               [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-03 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 8.00     [01] => 0 [02] => 0 [03] => 0 [04] => 2.00 [05] => 6.00 )
         [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => web dev | dev test | dev task   [taskstartdate] => 2016-02-04 00:00:00 [estimatedhours] => 30.00    [01] => 0 [02] => 0 [03] => 0 [04] => 8.00 [05] => 6.00)
```

I hope you can understand the logic and please comment if need more information for this.

This is beyond my understanding so I did not tryout code for this.

Best regards.

Comment: SO qestion is what you trie so far?

Comment: I did not try anything so far. Would appreciate hand for this :)

Comment: how is the first array populated ? where's that bit of code?

Comment: This is Codeigniter and I am populating this array using MySQL query by joining 4 tables.